# ComponentScan not mapping RestControllers

Tags: java, spring-boot

My Spring application is not mapping the `@RestController`. Seems to me it's a `ComponentScan` issue. I have two projects (the database and the API application) and I'm scanning both (I tried by `basePackages` and `value`).
But still not working.

Application class:

```
//@ComponentScan({"project.name.db", "project.name"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "project.name")
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

A controller:

```
@RestController
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping("/person")
    public List<Person> getPerson(@RequestParam int someId) throws Exception {
      return this.personService.getPerson(someId);
    }
}
```

When Spring is loading, output doesn't contains this `/person` map.
What can it be?

**UPDATING PROJECT STRUCTURE**

*project.name.db*

- *models*
- *repository*

*project.name*

- MyApplication.java
- *controllers*
- *services*

The *italic* texts are packages.

Comment: can you post your project structure. I want to see the packages and classes.

Comment: *I have two projects (the database and the API application)* did you import the configuration class of db inside **UI** module?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas the dependencies are set. There's no configuration class in db project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are options:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "your.toplevel.package")
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses= {PersonController.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "project.name")
```

You dont need the `@ComponentScan` if your main class (i.e. `MyApplication`) sits in the root package. Spring boot will automatically scan those.